# What wrong did Mank and Marion Davies do to each other that they are now forgiving each other for?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In a scene from *Mank* (2020), the car is parked beneath a tree. Mank and Marion sit
on the ground upon a table cloth. They drink and discuss about
"Citizen Kane" script:

> Mank: I hope, if this gets made, you'll **forgive me**.
>
> Marion Davis: And I hope, if it doesn't, you'll **forgive me**.

What wrong did Mank and Marion Davis do to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mank was apologizing because his script for *Citizen Kane* included a character that was based on Davies but was depicted as a terribly untalented performer, while Davies was quite talented in real life.

Davies was apologizing because her lover and benefactor, William Randolph Hearst, was trying to prevent *Citizen Kane* from being released.

From the Wikipedia entries for *Citizen Kane* and Marion Davies:

> Many assumed that the character of Susan Alexander Kane was based on
> Marion Davies, Hearst's mistress whose career he managed and whom
> Hearst promoted as a motion picture actress. This assumption was a
> major reason Hearst tried to destroy Citizen Kane...
>
> By the time of her death, her popular association with the character
> of Susan Alexander Kane in the film Citizen Kane (1941) already
> overshadowed Davies' legacy as a talented actress. The title
> character's second wife—an untalented singer whom he tries to
> promote—was widely assumed to be based upon Davies. However, many
> commentators, including writer-director Orson Welles, defended
> Davies's record as a gifted actress and comedienne to whom Hearst's
> patronage did more harm than good.